# Outer Glow for UIView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, nstextfield

I am wondering how I can create an outer glow effect outside a UIView on the iPhone, kind of like when clicking a regular NSTextField on the Mac.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a custom subview to your UIView that extends beyond the bounds of your UIView.  For example:

```
UITextView* mainView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)];
mainView.clipsToBounds = NO;

// Add 5 px of padding to the mainView bounds
CGRect borderFrame = CGRectInset(mainView.bounds, -5, -5);
MyBorderView* borderView = [[MyBorderView alloc] initWithFrame:borderFrame];
customView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[mainView addSubview:customView];
```

`MyBorderView` can draw a border in its `-drawRect:` method, or you could use UIImageView.

Answer (score 3):

If your view is opaque, just add a shadow to its layer:

```
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
    view.layer.shadowColor = self.window!.tintColor.CGColor
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a background image, position it behind the TextField, and have it be slightly larger so the glow part of the image shows around the borders of the text field.